# Change links beginning from http:// to // so that https site can get correct CSS/JS files

Tags: https

What is the best way to Change links beginning from http:// to "//" so that https site can get correct CSS/JS files ?

I want visitors to either http:// or https:// can see correct CSS.

I want to do that by changing all refrences to js and css files to start with "//"

What is the best way to do this ?

so that they become:

src="//www.example.com/some-css.css"

Comment: Are you talking about enqueued css/js from plugins/theme, or are these coming from somewhere else?

Comment: @MattKeys I guess the css/js coming from themes and plugins, not sure what you mean with somewhere else.